# Close a Form and Refresh 2 combo boxes on the main form

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I am trying to refresh 2 combo boxes that have the same source after closing a child form.

This works for 1 combo box but I don't know how to add a second one without having to .Requery all the form.

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

[Forms!][Facturi]!**[ComboPresID]**.Requery

End Sub
```

But I also want to **[ComboBenID]**.Requery

I tried AND, &. I don't know where to learn about VBA.

Comment: Do the same as the other line, but on separate lines.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Now I feel like a total idiot.

Comment: And is used for things like if a=b AND c=d then, not to do more than 1 thing.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form_Close()

[Forms!][Facturi]![ComboPresID].Requery
[Forms!][Facturi]![ComboBenID].Requery

End Sub
```